# Event based trigger console command in Laravel

Tags: laravel, console

I would like to execute Laravel console command in background as soon as I click trigger button from fronted. Is there any event based trigger in Laravel ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the Artisan facade. For example,

```
Artisan::call('route:list');
```

Documentation for this is available at https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands